# Rabies in spiders - is it possible?

Tags: entomology, virology

What if we inject rabies virus into an insect body, like spider or a bee, will it contract rabies as humans, cats, dogs, racoons or bats do?

Answer (score 3):

Rabies is a viral disease that causes inflammation of the brain. It is adapted to the nervous systems of vertebrates particularly mammals. Arthropods are too different for lyssaviruses to survive in their body.

Comment: I'd like to ask you a question since I have not enough knowledge of biology and also assuming you'd like to speculate a bit. So the virus enters the body of a spider (let's take a spider as a example) and then what? To put it more metaphorically, the lyssvirus looks around, realizes the host is not a mammal and disappears? I'd like to know how it goes with lyssaviruses, but (to anyone) take it as an invitation to a discussion.